# Find $\operatorname{Cl }A$ in topological space $\mathbb{R^2}$ with dictionary order topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $ A = \left\{  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid  y= \sin ( \frac{1}{x}) , \  0 < x \leq 1 \right\}$ . Find $\operatorname{Cl} A$ in topological space $\mathbb{R^2}$ with dictionary order topology.

I guess $ \operatorname{Cl} A = A $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite right. To prove it, I would take an arbitrary point not in $A,$ and find an open interval around it containing no points of $A.$ This shows that the complement of $A$ is open, so that $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The plane in the dictionary order is basically $\mathbb{R}$ many disjoint topological copies of vertical stalks that are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. So the closure can be taken in each “stalk”. Your $A$ intersects each stalk in a singleton or the emptyset, so the closure is just $A$ as you claim.

Comment: Depending on the level of the proposer it might be more helpful to emphasize that each "stalk" is open-and-closed.